# how to send multipart data in the form of form data in android using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, multipart

[This is the way i have to send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4bE.png)

I have tried with many answers but is not able to undersatnd the data value and the method used . i m new to multipart . Kindly help

This is the code it returns satus ok but returns response code as null

```
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        File uploadFile1 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161127_101131.jpg");
        String requestURL = "http://10.238.48.30:8081/socialapi/social/addimage/v1/51";
         URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true); 
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
            true);
    String fileName = uploadFile1.getName();

    writer.append(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + "uploadimage"
                    + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    /*writer.append(
            "Content-Type: "
                    + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
            .append(LINE_FEED);*/
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
    //writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();

       writer.flush();
   // writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.close();

    // checks server's status code first
    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpConn.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }

    return response;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please format your question by including your actual code as text, indented by four or more spaces.  Screen captures of code should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Use some http cleint libraries e.g Retrofit 2.0 , This will make job easier

Comment: Isnt there any other way apart from using libraries . Found this http://www.androidsnippets.com/multipart-http-requests.html but not able to understand what are the parameters to be passed , given my form data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did as you said